# Why does \big\setminus not work?

Tags: math-mode, bigdelim

The two macros `\setminus` and `\backslash` both produce a backslash in mathmode that is customarily used to denote, well, set differences: $A\setminus B$, $A\backslash B$.

For `\backslash` there are also a `\big`ger versions, e.g., `\big\backslash`, whereas `\big\setminus` creates an error.

Why is that so?
Should we not consider this a bug in `\setminus`?

Comment: No operation symbol grows with `\big`; why should `\setminus` behave differently?

Comment: @egreg How about `\big/` or `\Bigg/`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that's a delimiter (non zero delcode)

Comment: OK, TeXnically, the question is answered. Typographically, is it a bad idea to let the set-difference operator scale up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is in their definition in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\backslash}    % for double coset G\backslash H
   {\mathord}{symbols}{"6E}{largesymbols}{"0F}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\setminus}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"6E}
```

or, in `plain.tex`,

```
\def\backslash{\delimiter"26E30F } % for double coset G\backslash H

\mathchardef\setminus="226E % for set difference A\setminus B
```

Note that if you do `texdef -t latex backslash` and `texdef -t latex setminus` you get

```
\backslash:
macro:->\delimiter "026E30F 

\setminus:
\mathchar"226E
```

so there's no real difference between the two cases.

There's a substantial definition between a delimiter and a mathchar. The former type will honor `\big` and friends or `\left` and `\right`, the latter won't.

Note that `\backslash` is defined to be class 0 (ordinary symbol) when used alone, whereas `\setminus` has class 2 (binary operation symbol); this will affect spacing.

If you need a “bigger `\setminus`” you can do

```
\mathbin{\big\backslash}
```

but `\big\setminus` would be like `\big+` that's not going to work, because `\big` *needs* a delimiter after it, that is, either a character with a nonzero `\delcode` or a macro expanding to `\delimiter<27 bit number>`.

The usage of `\setminus` is very different from `/` that, traditionally, has no space on either side and so TeX treats it as an ordinary symbol, also assigning it a nonzero `\delcode`

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{operators}{"2F}{largesymbols}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{/}{\mathord}{letters}{"3D}
```

in LaTeX, and

```
\mathcode`\/="013D
\delcode`\/="02F30E
```

in plain TeX.

Comment: +1 for the workaround, `\mathbin{\big\backslash}`